# Protected Routes using React

Tags: reactjs

Going through resources on creating protected routes in React, I came across the following example

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

I can make use of the component by

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/books" component={Book} />
```

So I've the following doubts on the above code segment

- The protected route is passed as `component` but why's the `Component` tag used?
- Also, if the rest of the properties are passed as `...rest` to `Route` where does the `render` method gets its `props` from?

Comment: This syntax: `component: Component` is like an alias in  Javascript, it renames something. So the actual `component` you pass is then referred to as `Component` inside the function. And the render method gets its props from the `Route` component itself, which has the functionality of passing the relevant `props` object to its own `render` prop

Comment: So ```...rest``` is only containing the path? ie. ```"/books"```?

Comment: It contains **all** the other props not already destructured, in this `exact` and `path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

In Javascript, we can rename the key while destructuring using colon(:) as in `component:Component` The reason to do this is we cannot directly destructure `Component` since it is a reserved keyword in React.

2.

`...rest` is props for Route component. For example: In, `<Route exact path="/books" component={Book} />`, 'exact' and 'path' are props for Route component not for Book.

To pass props for Book component, react-router allows us to use render prop. render prop accepts a function and returns a component. react-router handles the passing of props from Route component to our Book component for us.